# update array of object and setState using shorthand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Was trying to rewrite my update array of object using shorter version but failed, I have a working version,
which assign to a tempporary variable before setState.

```
//working version
const new_items = (this.state.new_items || []).map((o, i) => {
    if(i === idx) {
        return e.target.value
    }
    return o
})
this.setState({
    items: new_items
})

//shorter version but why snytax error?
this.setState({
    items: (this.state.items || []).map((o, i)=> ({
        i === idx ? e.target.value : o
    }))
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return* the `e.target.value` or the `o`. As is, the inside of your `map` function is just an orphaned expression that's not connected to anything, which won't work.

Best thing to do would be to have the arrow function implicitly return, by removing the `{` `}`s:

```
this.setState({
  items: (this.state.templates || []).map((o, i) => (
    i === idx ? e.target.value : o
  ))
});
```

Comment: Just want to note that you can implicitly return an object along with the object shorthand notation `(item) => ({item})` is valid as long as `item` is valid as an object key.